# .htaccess regular expressions for optimal performance?

Tags: apache-2.2, security, hosting, .htaccess

In my .htaccess file I'm trying to block some bots using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^badbot [NC]
```

But, I want to change these conditions to something more inclusive like:

Method #1:  `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*badbot [NC,OR]`

OR

Method #2:  `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*badbot [NC,OR]`

OR

Method #3:  `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} badbot [NC,OR]`

The question is, which one of those 3 methods would be best for server performance?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this website. I didn't realize I was supposed to do that. I will go back and accept the best answers.

Comment: Then apologies for the tone of my comment. Some users just don't accept answers at all.

Comment: It may take a while for that to update - I think some details are refreshed every so often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is little performance difference between these. Logically, the `/.*badbot/` and `/badbot/` should be equivalent, and as regular expressions are parsed from left to right I would also have thought the `^` made no difference.

I did test these with Perl (which may use a slightly different regex engine to mod_rewrite) and it did show `/badbot/` to be quite a bit quicker than the others, but this could be down to the strings I was using. Also, bearing in mind that USER_AGENT has a maximum length of 200, this is probably unnecessary optimization. You'd get more optimization by placing these inside the `httpd.conf` instead of `.htaccess`.

The results I got from testing are:

```
[james@aladdin ~]$ time perl -e 'my $x = "bad" x 99999999; $x .= "badbot"; print "true" if $x =~ /^.*badbot/;'  
true  
real    0m2.575s  
user    0m1.847s  
sys 0m0.712s  
[james@aladdin ~]$ time perl -e 'my $x = "bad" x 99999999; $x .= "badbot"; print "true" if $x =~ /badbot/;'  
true  
real    0m2.110s  
user    0m1.378s  
sys 0m0.691s  
[james@aladdin ~]$ time perl -e 'my $x = "bad" x 99999999; $x .= "badbot"; print "true" if $x =~ /.*badbot/;'  
true  
real    0m2.522s  
user    0m1.866s  
sys 0m0.647s
```

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. So you're saying that method #3 would be best? Without the .* OR ^.*

Comment: From testing, yes it seems so, but I can't understand why. It could be down to the strings being used - if it's using the Boyer-Moore algorithm then it will search for the last character of the string first and work back from there (so would be fast with the above example) - see http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html - although I did replace the "bad" with "bot" to see if that made a difference and #3 was still faster. I wish I knew why.

Comment: I guess I'll go with method #3 then. I'm just wondering if using a rewrite rule to "block" the thousands of bot requests that I'm receiving would increase the server's cpu usage versus the bandwidth that would be saved by using my .htaccess file. In other words, ignore the bots and let them waste bandwidth or block the bots and use cpu power to block them. Am I correct to think this?

Answer (score 1):

If your looking for optimal performance...
Firstly have Apache ignore/skip looking for .ht files..
Disable .htaccess.. :D

```
AllowOverride None
```

And put your stuff/rewrites/etc directly in each vhost..

And then choose 1,2 or 3 :D

Then you have already taken a step towards "faster"

Hope this helps.. :D

Comment: I'm on a shared server so I don't have access to the Apache config. Would AllowOverride None still benefit me? From what I understand it just disables .htaccess files in all sub-directories, but keeps the main .htaccess file active, right?

Comment: Yes... you can also turn it off completely..

Which stops reading these files dynamically on EVERY call..
-----First it stats the disk in every folder, reads the file, parses the content, applies the rules.. ( you can see this being heavy across a busy server ) in fact, its completely stupid by design..

Comment: Okay, so according to the Apache docs I can only have AllowOverride None in <Directory>. I want my main .htaccess file in public_html to still apply to all directories (my entire site), but I don't want the server to search for any .htaccess files in those sub-directories. So what would I put in <Directory>?

Comment: I don't think that the local .htaccess scheme is stupid, since it will only parse the files *if they are present*, which should be false for most directories. Also, it's very useful in shared hosting, since it's a good and simple way of change some server settings without touching the global settings. Of course, if you put the same configuration in each folder instead of using the root folder I agree that it's a bit stupid, but is the admin fault.

Comment: Do you think stat'ing the disk for every folder is intelligent/logical considering that there is a VERY high chance it doesnt exist? Basically any serious Apache deployment will turn this off (IMHO it should be default)

Comment: For shared hosting, well i absolutely agree with your comment :)